# How to limit connections for java.net.http.HttpClient

Tags: java, java-http-client

How to limit the number of connection/request for java.net.http.HttpClient?

I see I can set an Executor to HttpClient but I don't know: if I limit the number of thread in pool of Executor, is it limit also the number of connection?

Another way to limit the number of connection?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need to limit the connections for java.net.http.HttpClient?

Comment: Because the HTTP server authorize only 10 connections max. So I want to be sure to execute only 10 request simultaneous and put next "in a queue"

Comment: I wonder if I set an executor like new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>()); I have the warranty I don't exceed the connection limit (10).

Comment: Maybe this SO thread can be of some help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302936/java-11-httpclient-what-is-optimum-ratio-of-httpclients-to-concurrent-httprequ .

Comment: Use a bounded blocking queue when building the Executor, and a fixed size thread pool.

Comment: I read the page @Maurice. An I read the code but I 'm not sure. I think if I have a thread pool executor with maximum 10 threads, I can have more than 10 connections because there is some compose on computable future used in sendAsync (but I don't know if exchange is atomic (connection/request/receipt response), I want to say in one thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To limit the number of concurrent requests made through the HttpClient you will have to do so at the application level. The HttpClient is purely asynchronous so limiting the number of threads in the HttpClient executor will not work. Similarly, limiting the number of connections in the keep-alive pool will not work, since the pool contains only *idle* connections.

It should be very easy to limit the number of concurrent requests at the application level by guarding the code that sends requests with a simple semaphore (see [java.util.concurrent.Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)). To limit the number of concurrent requests to e.g. 10 requests, just create a semaphore with 10 permits, acquire the semaphore before sending a request and release it when the response has arrived.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP/1.1 connection pool size is controlled by the jdk.httpclient.connectionPoolSize system property. If unset it defaults to unlimited connections.